# Should I compare integers using the operator or a method?

Tags: c#

I'm refactoring my clients code written by an unspecified coder. It looks like this.

```
int i = ...;
if (i.Equals(123));
```

I'm **very** tempted to change it to the usual, namely:

```
int i = ...;
if (i == 123);
```

but I'm cautious not to cause any damage. Those calls are equivalent, aren't they? And by any measures, the operator style can't be slower but is definitely more surprising and less readable, right?

Comment: Those calls are **not** equivalent, by **any** measures. Never will be. You placed your hand to far up the num pad on the latter.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - You are correct!  But I believe "456" was a typo.  It has been corrected, so the two statements should now be equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisGessler That's why my tests failed... :(

Answer (score 3):

For [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) use `==` operator, since `Equals` is usually useful with [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx). Since int is a value type it is better to use `==` operator. There is one exception to the rule and that is for strings, since string is a reference type but `==` operator is overloaded in .Net framework to check for equality.

> those calls are equivalent, aren't they?

They are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

[When should I use == and when should I use Equals?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx)

Something I didn't know either :)

> Value types do not provide an overload for == by default. However,
>   most of the value types provided by the framework provide their own
>   overload. The default implementation of Equals for a value type is
>   provided by ValueType, and uses reflection to make the comparison,
>   which makes it significantly slower than a type-specific
>   implementation normally would be. This implementation also calls
>   Equals on pairs of references within the two values being compared.

Additionally, I use `==` on strings to avoid the null check.

```
if(myString == "something")
```

vs

```
if(myString != null && myString.Equals("something"))
```

Comment: Hey - you corrected OP's typo. Now my comment looks like a donkey... :)

Comment: Yeah. And I got downvoted for that too... If this repeats (myCurrStat)/2 times more, I'll be down to zero! Terrible... And I should get **upvoted** for my keen eyes and sharp sense of humor. HAHAHA!

Comment: @KonradViltersten - fix your answer so the downvotes can be removed. Yes, you have keen eyes - but why not see past the obvious typo or correct it instead?

Comment: Of course it was obvious. I even offered an explanation as to **how** it happened (three finger shot an inch too high on the num pad). To answer your question - "to tease is to please", hihi. But I'm prone to agree with you. I'll cut the first part of my answer. But how do you mean "downvotes can be removed"? Not that I care a lot but it's interesting to learn. And +1 for the blog link.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - After a down or up vote has been set, it can only be removed when the user changes his/her answer.  The other way to remove all the downvotes is to delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're declaring the variable as *int*, it's a value type and it's recommended to go with the operator style. The method style is to be applied on object typed variables.

You can compare [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and [object types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

Comment: could you also explain the differences for me and for others?

Comment: @Freeman Sure. 456 - 123 != 0. But you need to see the original post. Now it's been corrected. Of course, we are agreed in the principle. I was just being a nit-pick.

Comment: I really dont get your answer, of course 333 != 0. And hey, i have a great sense of humour.

Comment: @Freeman Exactly. It's not equal. And the OP wrote those numbers asking if the calls were equivalent. They never will be.